# How to write a behavior that can host a variable number of child properties/elements/xaml-tags

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, behavior

I created an `Interaction.Behavior` behavior that needs to receive a variable amount of input.

For this, the behavior has a `List<>` Dependency property to receive content:

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey FocusTargetsPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Targets", typeof(List<FocusTarget>), typeof(StatefulFocusManagerBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new List<FocusTarget>()));

public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusTargetsProperty = FocusTargetsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public List<FocusTarget> Targets
{
    get => (List<FocusTarget>)this.GetValue(FocusTargetsProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(FocusTargetsProperty, value);
}
```

And the content is implemented as a class `FocusTarget` that derives from `FrameworkElement`:

```
public class FocusTarget : FrameworkElement
{
    
    #region DepProp: FocusTarget

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Target", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(FocusTarget), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public FrameworkElement Target
    {
        get => (FrameworkElement)this.GetValue(FocusTargetProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(FocusTargetProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    #region DepProp: StateName

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StateName", typeof(string), typeof(FocusTarget), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string StateName
    {
        get => (string)this.GetValue(StateNameProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(StateNameProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The Behavior is declared as follows:

```
<b:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behav:StatefulFocusManagerBehavior FocusTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtResponse}">
        <behav:StatefulFocusManagerBehavior.Targets>
            <behav:FocusTarget Target="{Binding ElementName=txtResponse}"  StateName="Text"  />
            <behav:FocusTarget Target="{Binding ElementName=QnAToggle}"    StateName="Toggle"/>
        </behav:StatefulFocusManagerBehavior.Targets>
    </behav:StatefulFocusManagerBehavior>
</b:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Now there is what works:

- The `behav:StatefulFocusManagerBehavior` has its `FocusTarget` property binding is working as expected
- The `behav:FocusTarget` instances hast their property `StateName` set as expected
- The `behav:FocusTarget` instances have their `Target` property **always set to null**

I did suspect this could be a DataContext issue but could not verify nor dismiss it, leaving me puzzled on the possible issue and solution.

I tried to set the DataContext but this binding to is not working and giving me null:

```
<behav:FocusTarget Target="{Binding ElementName=txtResponse}"   
                   StateName="Text"
                   DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheriting the data context and accessing elements from a behavior collection does not work that way, because the collection is not in the visual tree and not a `FrameworkElement` or `Freezable` that enable binding.

Change the `FocusTargetsProperty` to a `FreezableCollection<FocusTarget>` instead of a `List<FocusTarget>`. Furthermore, make sure that you assign a new instance of the collection in the constructor.

```
public class StatefulFocusManagerBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
   private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey FocusTargetsPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Targets", typeof(FreezableCollection<FocusTarget>), typeof(StatefulFocusManagerBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusTargetsProperty = FocusTargetsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

   public FreezableCollection<FocusTarget> Targets
   {
      get => (FreezableCollection<FocusTarget>)this.GetValue(FocusTargetsProperty);
      set => this.SetValue(FocusTargetsProperty, value);
   }

   public StatefulFocusManagerBehavior()
   {
      SetValue(FocusTargetsPropertyKey, new FreezableCollection<FocusTarget>());
   }
}
```

Then, instead of inheriting from `FrameworkElement` in `FocusTarget`, derive from `Freezable`.

```
public class FocusTarget : Freezable
{
   protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
   {
      return new FocusTarget();
   }

   // ...your other code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Any reason why you did not initialize the property using `new PropertyMetadata(new FreezableCollection<FocusTarget>())` in the RegisterReadOnly call?

Comment: OK I did it the way you proposed, not declaring the default value but setting one in the default constructor: WORKS LIKE A CHARM!!! (though I do not really understand what goes on under the hood, as using a default value complained about IsFrozen needing to be false?!). Thank you so much!

Comment: @John440 You should always initialize collection dependency properties in the constructor, otherwise the default value instance is shared. See [Initializing the Collection Beyond the Default Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/collection-type-dependency-properties?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#initializing-the-collection-beyond-the-default-value) for more information.

Comment: OK that makes a lot of sense and finally explains a strange side effect I had on another topic :) I guess I would never have found it out on my own.